# onclick does not fire in first Item in GalleryView 1.1

Tags: jquery-plugins, galleryview

So I have a page using GalleryView 1.1 [here](http://www.mitchsflowers.dreamhosters.com/weddings.php).  I like the behaviors just fine except that the left-most item's onclick event won't fire for some reason.

I also grabbed the 2.1 version from the GoogleCode page; the author's page at http://spaceforaname.com/ has gone.  So [here is a page](http://www.mitchsflowers.dreamhosters.com/test.php) implementing 2.1.

Since 2.1 has a bunch of behaviors I hate and seems to completely prevent my onclick events I would like to sort out the issue with the left-most item's onclick in the v1 page.

I have read through the code but failed to find what is interfering.

The function looks like this:

```
 $('.myslides').click(function() {
    //alert($(this).attr('alt'));
     $('#big_pic').attr("src", $(this).attr('alt'));
     return false;
  });
```

and the items like this

```
<li><img src='g/weddings/slides/1.jpg' width='165' height='110' alt='/g/weddings/slides/1_big.jpg' class='myslides'/></li>
```

I have tried moving the class attribute to the LI, and also adding an anchor around the image and giving it the class but neither of these had a visible effect.

// Edit
The [page validates](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.mitchsflowers.dreamhosters.com/weddings.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.2) and yes I know the big pics are blurry.  Don't have them from GD so did best I could stretching thumbs.

Does anyone have an idea of how I should pursue debugging this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when inspecting the elements in question I found that the working thumbnails were all image elements but the non working first thumbnail was a div with id "pointer".

Since the author's site with the docs has evaporated I can say what function #pointer has in my filmstrip slides but in jquery.galleryview-1.1.js on line 319 I changed its width to 1px in the JS CSS and this resolved the issue of the obstructed onclick.  #pointer may have a function I am not employing here.  At any rate the issue is resolved.

Width was previously set to

```
'width':opts.frame_width-pointer_width+'px',
```

Now set to

```
pointer.attr('id','pointer').appendTo(j_gallery).css({
                 'position':'absolute',
                 'zIndex':'1000',
                 'cursor':'pointer',
                 'top':getPos(j_frames[0]).top-(pointer_width/2)+'px',
                 'left':getPos(j_frames[0]).left-(pointer_width/2)+'px',
                 'height':opts.frame_height-pointer_width+'px',
                 '1px',
                 'border':(has_panels?pointer_width+'px solid '+(opts.nav_theme=='dark'?'black':'white'):'none')
            });
```

Also tried adding display:none but this resulted in jerky animation.